# Proving that the Fisher transformation maps $−1 < a < 1$ to the reals

Tags: self-study

Prove that the “Fisher transformation” maps $−1 < a < 1$ to the reals, $R$. The Fisher transformation is defined as $f(a) = \text{logit}[(a+1)/2]=\log[(1+a)/(1-a)]$.

So far I have thought that

$-1< a <1$

$0< 1+a <2$

$-1< a <1$

$-1< -a <1$

$ 0< 1-a <2$

$0<(1+a)/(1-a)$

$\log[(1+a)/(1-a)]$

Are my steps so far correct? And where would I go from here?

Comment: it's not hard to see that the endpoints, $a = -1, 1$ map $(1+a)/(1-a) $ to $0, \infty$, respectively; taking the log changes that to $-\infty, \infty$, respectively. After that, just show $(1+a)/(1-a)$ is monotonically increasing in $a$, using derivatives, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting rid of the log right away. So if $\log([x_\min,x_\max])=[-\infty,+\infty]$, what must the interval $[x_\min,x_\max]$ be?

You must then show that for $a\in[-1,1]$ your argument $\frac{1+a}{1-a}$ both 1) covers this interval, and 2) does not go outside this interval.

(Note that for simplicity the above uses the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), and correspondingly the closed interval $-1\leq a \leq +1$.)